# localhost direct Access

Tags: php, localhost, wampserver

Friends

There are little problem those get me confused.

I have submitted one project to client, which is totally non-technical.

Project is for local use only.

So 2 problems are there. First he has to start wampserver & second he has to open browser & type
 localhost

For Second Problem I have Created Shortcut on Desktop, but 1st still not solved.

Is there any way, wamp server automatically start, when he starts pc???

Any help would be appriciable,

Thanks.

Comment: Put the shortcut of WAMP Server into Startup folder.

Comment: You can set localhost as a startup page from browser's options panel.

Comment: you can use msconfig to start wamp server automatically on each  boot up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around your question, I can't believe I didn't think of it before:

1. Log in as an administrator.
2. Start -> Run "services.msc"
3. Right click the service wampapache, go to properties, and set startup type to 'Automatic'
4. Repeat step 3 but for wampmysqld (if you want MySQL to also be available on startup)

   OR

   You can make one batch file will start your server as well as browser localhost.

You can set the property.

Comment: @g patel, Thank you so much bro, I got the solution.thanks a lot

Comment: Always Welcome Friends :-)

Answer (score 0):

just create a shortcut in desktop to start wampserver then

Comment: That's what the questioner wrote he did.

Answer (score 0):

put a short cut of wampserver in to "Startup" folder.
you can find it in all programs if you using win 7/vista
then it will automatically start when windows start.

Answer (score 0):

If it is sufficient that it starts up when the user logs in and his windows starts up, you can move/drag/copy the program 'start wampserver' from "Start > Program menu > wampserver" to your "Start  > Program menu > StartUp" folder.

If you need it running on booting, you will have to register/start it as a service. For that you need to go to "Start > Run" and type in:

```
services.msc
```

Followed by an enter. Then lookup these 2 services:

```
wampapache
wampmysql
```

You then need to right click and choose properties. On the General tab change the startup from manual to automatic". Also check the "Log On" tab where you can provide your user credentials so you can start it up without needing to log in.

For your second problem: you can create a bookmark or set your browser's homepage to point to localhost.